# Adding action listeners to strings

Tags: java

I'm trying to add an action listener to a string added to a JMenu... Not sure how to do so, the JavaDoc doesn't make it any easier to find out how. Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 234614L;

private static final JMenuBar menbar = new JMenuBar();

private static final JMenu blocks = new JMenu("name");
private static final JMenu items = new JMenu("name2");

private static final JMenu edit = new JMenu("Edit");

    public GUI(){

        this.setSize(300, 200);
        this.setTitle("");

        this.setJMenuBar(menbar);

        menbar.add(blocks);
        menbar.add(items);
        menbar.add(edit);

        blocks.add("Stone");

        blocks.addActionListener(this);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {



    }

}
```

Comment: I'm trying to add an action listener to the String

Comment: Ah, to be twelve years old again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.add(String s)` returns a `JMenuItem`, you need to take that reference and you'll be able to add an Action Listener.

```
JMenuItem stoneMenuItem = blocks.add("Stone");
stoneMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    // My stuff!
});
```